# Why does the actual CPU usage seem to be double what is reported for active processes?

Tags: windows, windows-10

My CPU shows heavy utilisation in Resource Monitor, but if I select all processes, the combined CPU usage of all active processes comes to roughly (exactly?) half of total CPU usage (orange line in the graph below). Why does the actual usage seem to be double what is reported?

[image: graph of cpu usage]

Comment: Could be malware, hiding its process(es)?

Comment: I doubt it. The total vs 'reported' seems to track almost exactly. If you look at the graph, the peaks in the total seem amplified in the same places, but look twice as big (as if the 'reported' were added to itself). If it were malware, the peaks wouldn't coincide like that.

Comment: Should / could be kernel time, maybe.

Comment: How many logical processors does your system have?  (And what version of Windows 10 is that?  On my system, the Resource Monitor graph looks different.)

Comment: My processor is an Intel Core i5-8250u. It has 4 physical processors, but 8 logical processors (I think) because of Intel's Hyper-Threading technology. I wonder if the hyper threading is the cause of the mismatch?

Comment: (It's Windows 10 Home).

Comment: @KonradGajewski yes

Comment: analyze [CPU usage with Windows Performance Toolkit](https://superuser.com/a/1203562/174557)

Comment: I'm not sure that orange line is a combined view.  My Resmon chart has 2 lines, one for frequency (on top) and one for utilization.  The spikes would tend to correlate with higher CPU demand increasing frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Try running processexplorer (Windows Sysinternals free download) to investigate further what is causing the consumption.

In there you can expand each process and see processes that sometimes not showing in the regular task manager.

Comment: Sysinternals shows a total CPU usage similar to the 'reported' values in Resource Monitor. No hidden processes apparent, but seemingly a more accurate total usage report.

Comment: The System Idle Process does take up a lot, but my understanding is that that reports available capacity - it doesn't contribute to the roughly 44% reported CPU usage.

Comment: I would assume that this is due to processexplorer giving much closer readings on all processes, whereas task manager keeps a lot of 0% process utilization which is obviously false. My point being that the remaining 40% is most likely the sum of all the other CPU demanding tasks that they can't catch. I could see a similar pattern on my computer just now.

Comment: If that were true (40% of usage is made up of short-lived processes that don't show up in the report), then I would expect the CPU usage to be at least 40% even when idle. I don't think that's the case here (can't test right now since it's a busy with a processor-intensive task that I can't cancel).

Comment: No because that depends on what you are running. It could as well be the same processes you are running that are spiking without any monitoring tool catching it. It can also be some false-positives being sent to the CPU as it is a multicore (and multi-thread) processor.